# Symfony2: Issue when using jsRoutingBundle in production site

Tags: symfony

I'm currently working in a Symfony 2.3 project, in which we have just installed jsRoutingBundle, we need it to help us with our AJAX calls.

We have followed successfully the installing and implementation instructions but we are stuck for few days in the same point.

I'm using Firebug to debug javascripts errors; and I get the following error:

```
Error: The route "B.GeoEntity.SearchFromForm" does not exist.
```

The route definition on my bundle's routing.yml file is the following:

```
B.GeoEntity.SearchFromForm:
    path:     /geoentity/search
    defaults: { _controller: BackendBundle:GeoEntity:searchFromForm }
    options:
        expose: true
```

Already used..

```
fos_js_routing:
    routes_to_expose: [ B.GeoEntity.SearchFromForm ]
```

...in app's config.yml, but it still doesn't work.

Anyone's got any clue?

**EDIT:**

I have tested it in a different machine, and I get the following error via FireBug:

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://******.com/js/routing?callback=fos.router.setdata"
```

Comment: Are you sure that you can use dots within route names? I've never seen anyone do that before and it might be the issue here

Comment: While developement everything works well; the problem is only when trying to make it work in the production site. Anyway i'll try

Comment: Clear the cache
```app/console cache:clear --env=prod``` or remove the app/cache/prod folder through FTP/SCP whatever.

Comment: Did it a bunch of times but we're not having any positive result...

Comment: umm, uploaded all files?

Comment: Yep, we have deployed the whole web twice, still getting the same error at the same point